# using regex to validate messages from array

Tags: javascript

The below snippet works, but is there a better way

```
 const ignoreMessages = [
      `a`,
      `b 'more'`,
    ];
    
const regexMessage = /Loading page [\d]+ down/;

if(!ignoreMessages.includes(error?.message) || !(regexMessage.test(error?.message))){
  return 'Different error'
}
```

Currently my `regexMessage` is a different one, how can include the `regexMessage` also in `ignoreMessages` so that if its part of `ignoreMessages` then I don't want to return 'Different error'. Because all three messages should be ignorable ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a function that check the message against strings or regular expressions.

```js
function check_error(m){
  const ignoreMessages = [
        `a`,
        `b 'more'`,
        /Loading page [\d]+ down/
      ];


  if(ignoreMessages.some(s => s.test ? s.test(m) : s === m)){
    return m
  }else{
    return 'Different error';
  }
}


console.log(check_error('a'))
console.log(check_error('b'))
console.log(check_error('Loading page 27839 down'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `some` and `RegExp` (to convert strings to regex as well e.g `a` becomes `/a/`)

```js
function getErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
  const ignoreMessages = [
    `a`,
    `b 'more'`,
    /Loading page [\d]+ down/
  ];

  if (!ignoreMessages.some(ignoreMessage => new RegExp(ignoreMessage).test(errorMessage))) {
    return 'Different error'
  }
  return errorMessage
}

console.log(getErrorMessage("abc"))
console.log(getErrorMessage("b 'more' here"))
console.log(getErrorMessage("Loading page 1 down"))
console.log(getErrorMessage("Test")) //Different error
```